# Beginner to Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am newcomer to javascript and trying to write some simple code. All I am doing in this bit is find out how many gallons I have left in the car. I just can't seem to get the result to show up. Any help would be appreciated

```
 <!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var gasMilage = document.getElementById("mpg");
// getting the percent of the tank left
var gasReading = document.getElementById("tank_reading") / 100;
var gasTank = document.getElementById("tank_capacity");


 function getGallons(){
var gallons = gasReading * gasTank;

window.alert(gallons);
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style>


form input{
display:block;
}


</style>

<form name=test>
MPG<input type="text" id="mpg" name="mpg">
Gas Tank Reading<input type="text" id="tank_reading" name="tank_reading">
Tank Capacity<input type="text" id="tank_capacity" name="tank_capacity">
<input type="submit" onclick=getGallons()>
<input name=result readonly > 
</form>






</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the lines

```
var gasMilage ...
var gasReading ...
var gasTank ...
```

into your function. You are trying to read the values before the elements are on the page. Look at your console [F12] and you will see the error messages.

Second you will need to read the values of the element. You are just referencing the element.

```
var gasReading = document.getElementById("tank_reading").value / 100;
                                                        ^^^^^^
```

You will also find out you need to cancel the form submission.

Comment: Also should probably grab the `value` of the elements, and parse them.

Comment: LOL, I missed that. Updated.

Comment: Excuse me being nitpicky but I have heard of browsers that won't open dev tools on F12

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JavaScript function within your html in single-quotes or double-quotes:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="getGallons();">
```

Also try putting a `.innerHTML` after the `document.getElementById()'s`.  Works for me sometimes.
Also:

```
<input name="result" readonly >
```

Don't know what readonly is, but hope this helps.